# How to insert HTML, PHP content into database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to store my PHP returned HTML code into a MySQL database. I have manually inserted into database. But when I fetch that data from the database, it is showing an error and the PHP code is not decoding.

For example: $title has value but it shows $title.

The error:
[image]

My controller:

```
$url_data=$this->capcee_news->get_site_details($default_url);
$data['title']=$url_data['vchr_paper_name'];
$data['header']=$url_data['part1'];
$this->load->view('blank',$data);
```

My model:

```
public function get_site_details($url='')
{
    if(!empty($url)){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->tables['papers']);
        $this->db->join('tbl_template','tbl_news_paper.theme_id=tbl_template.pk_int_temp_id');
        $this->db->where('site_url',$url);
        $data=$this->db->get()->row_array();
        return $data;}
    return false;
}
```

My view:

```
echo $header;
```

Database content:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title><?=$title;?></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: `it showing error` => post them.

Comment: Update your question with the model function

Comment: I have updated my question with model code. please check it @wolfgang1983

Comment: Please check attached link which is error showing page

Comment: Try not using short code. <?php echo $title;?> Edit: Oops, I posted this before I seen the answer below. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

can you use the actual php tags like

```
<?php echo $title; ?>
```

also can you please post more code samples ?

Comment: Yes that’s true first of all you need to use actual php tag